# how to write data for excel file in cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I'm new to Cypress, I want to know how to write data to xlsx file, I tried writing this way but it can't open xlsx file.

```
cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/DataTest/login_result.xlsx', '\nUsername : ' + Username + '\n' + '\nPassword : ' + Password + '\n' + '\nExpectedResult : ' + ExpectedResult + '\n' + '\nActualResult : ' + Asresult + '\n' + '\nResult :' + result + '\n').as('writeXlsxFile')
```

Comment: xlsx file is not just a plain text, so you likely need some JS library to do the hard work for you. At some places, `node-xlsx` library is mentioned, so perhaps you can have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the extension of the Excel file as xls. For example, in the code below, the word Hello is written in the Excel file

```
cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/Test.xls', 'Hello','UTF-8')
```